# xpath - get parent Id by children with condition

Tags: python, xml, xpath, contains

I have XML that looks like that:

```
<doc>   
    <H Id="4732894">
      <M Ind="aa">
        <A Id="G">A</A>
        <A Id="S">M</A>
      </M>
    </H>
    <H Id="4326789">
      <M Ind="aa">
        <A Id="G">B</A>
        <A Id="S">F</A>
      </M>
      <M Ind="ab">
        <A Id="G">B</A>
        <A Id="S">M</A>
      </M>
      <M Ind="ac">
        <A Id="G">3</A>
        <A Id="S">F</A>
      </M>
      <M Ind="ad">
        <A Id="G">2</A>
        <A Id="S">F</A>
      </M>
    </H>
</doc>
```

I need to take the `Id` of all the `H` elements that have `M` elements that have `A` elements with `Id=G`=`B` or `C` in the text, and `Id=S`=`F`.

So in this example the output should be just `4326789`, because the first `M` element in this `H` element fulfills the condition.

This is what I've tried:

```
"//H/M/A[@Id='G'][contains(text(),'B C']/../../@Id"
```

and it already raised an error (so I didn't even try to add the `and` also for `@Id='S'`).

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below XPath to get required output:

```
//H[M[A[@Id="G" and .="B"] and A[@Id="S" and .="F"]]]/@id
```

*Output:*

```
4326789
```

Note that `.="F"` search for node with text content that is *equal to* `"F"` If you need `A` node that *contains* `"F"`, you can use `A[@Id="S" and contains(., "F")]`

Comment: `id` of an `H` which contains `M` which contains `A` which has `Id` equals to `G` and `text` equals to `B`. That sounds really make sense.

Comment: What a perfect answer!